# Spring JPA throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type exception for classes loaded from dependency jar

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am working with springmvc+jpa (No spring-boot) code base, we have some entity classes packaged in a jar with corresponding hbm mapping files and added as a dependency to the current project, we have two transaction managers, one is Hibernate based(which is working without issue) and another is jpa entityManager based which I am configuring like below

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories( basePackages = "<repopackage>", bootstrapMode = BootstrapMode.LAZY)
public class DataSourceConfig {
    
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean(DataSource dataSource,
            MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProvider,
            CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolver) {
        
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        props.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT , "DATABASE");
        props.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER,currentTenantIdentifierResolver);
        props.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, multiTenantConnectionProvider);
        props.put(Environment.DIALECT, "com.custom.PostgreSQLDialect");
        props.put(Environment.SCANNER_DISCOVERY, "class, hbm");
        props.put(Environment.ENABLE_LAZY_LOAD_NO_TRANS, "true");
        props.put(Environment.SHOW_SQL, "true");
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "<domain package in current project>", "domain package in dependency jar" });
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter apt = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(apt);
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaPropertyMap(props);
        return entityManagerFactory; 
    }

    @Bean(name="transactionManager") 
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

The configuration works fine for the entity classes with annotations in the current project, I can create repositories implementing `JpaRepository` interface and able to access it. Now, when I create repositories for the domain object present in dependency jar  I get this exception

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name &#39;resourceDetailRepository&#39;: 
FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.ResourceDetail
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:890)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
```

Comment: Could it be that the jar classes are annotated with `@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity`?

Comment: They are aren't annotated, but they have their corresponding hbm.xml mapping files in the same folder, I suppose they should have been scanned by entityManager.